# Pygame not checking keyevents after another happens

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am moving a sprite on the x-axis. It is properly moving left and right. When I press both LEFT and RIGHT at the same time it stop moving properly.

I am trying to make it when a user presses both keys and then lets go of one, for it to continue moving in the direction still pressed.

Weirdly it works while I holding right and letting go of left. It continues moving right.

When I hold left and tap right it stops moving until I press right again.

I commented out some ideas I had to make this work, but they failed me.

I am sure its a simple fix or a logic failure on my part.

I have worked a couple hours on this.

Thanks for responses ahead of time.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys
import math

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 1200
displayHeight = 800
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game 3')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class firstSquare:

    def __init__(self,player_x,player_y):

        self.x = player_x
        self.y = player_y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100

    def render(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

class secondSquare:

    def __init__(self,cpu_x,cpu_y):

        self.x = cpu_x
        self.y = cpu_y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100

    def render(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


player = firstSquare(300,300)
cpu = secondSquare(100,100)


def gameLoop():

### variables##
    player_x = 100
    player_y = 100
    x = 100
    y = 100
    movement_x = 0
    movement_y = 0
    frame_rate = 0
    frame_table = 0

    inGame = True



    while inGame:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                inGame = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            keyPressed= pygame.key.get_pressed()

#### this is moving the player on x-axis##

            if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                movement_x = -5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    movement_x = 0
            if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                movement_x = 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    movement_x = 0
### two keys at once won't move the player###

            if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                movement_x = 0

### pressing one key and letting go the other will continue movement

##            if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
##                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
##                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
##                        movement_x = 5
##                        print("left dropped")
##            if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
##                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
##                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
##                        movement_x = -5
##                        print("Right dropped")












        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        player.render()
        cpu.render()
        player.x += movement_x
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    movement_x = -5
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and movement_x < 0:
        movement_x = 0
if keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    movement_x = 5
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and movement_x > 0:
        movement_x = 0
```

And that would be it... Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code in your movement:

```
 if keyPressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                movement_x = -5
            elif keyPressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                movement_x = +5
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    movement_x = 0
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    movement_x = 0
```

Comment: I added the code in and it reversed the situation. Now the other direction won't work.